# Image_Picker Flutter, no image appears during compilation

Tags: flutter

here I have a problem when using Image_Picker under Flutter, my code looks good to me but I receive an error.
Indeed, no selected image appears during the execution of my code
Can you help me I join you my two classes for more understanding
Thank you

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class PageDescription extends StatefulWidget {
  final String identite;
  final String surnom;
  final String caracteristiques;
  final String role;

  PageDescription(this.identite, this.surnom, this.caracteristiques, this.role);

  @override
  _PageDescriptionState createState() => _PageDescriptionState();
}

class _PageDescriptionState extends State<PageDescription> {
  ImagePicker _imageFile = ImagePicker();
  File? _image;

  Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickFile = await _imageFile.getImage(source: source);
    setState(() {
      if (pickFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickFile.path);
      } else {
        print("Pas d'image selectionnée");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.identite),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => getImage(ImageSource.gallery),
              icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera))
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              _image == null
                  ? Text("Pas d'image selectionnée $_image")
                  : Image.file(_image!),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Identite: ${widget.identite}", textScaleFactor: 1.5),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Surnom: ${widget.surnom}", textScaleFactor: 1.5),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Caracteristiques: ${widget.caracteristiques}",
                  textScaleFactor: 1.5),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Rôle: ${widget.role}", textScaleFactor: 1.5)
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Error message in my debugging console:

```
Reloaded 0 libraries in 308ms.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(multiple_request, Cancelled by a second request, null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:597
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:158
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelImagePicker.pickImage
package:image_picker_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:29
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _PageDescriptionState.getImage
package:ampc_93/page_description.dart:22
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class PageDescription extends StatefulWidget {
  final String identite;
  final String surnom;
  final String caracteristiques;
  final String role;

  PageDescription(this.identite, this.surnom, this.caracteristiques, this.role);

  @override
  _PageDescriptionState createState() => _PageDescriptionState();
}

class _PageDescriptionState extends State<PageDescription> {
  
  File file;

  Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    File file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    setState(() {
      this.file = file;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.identite),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => getImage(ImageSource.gallery),
              icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera))
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              _image == null
                  ? Text("Pas d'image selectionnée $_image")
                  : Image.file(_image!),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Identite: ${widget.identite}", textScaleFactor: 1.5),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Surnom: ${widget.surnom}", textScaleFactor: 1.5),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Caracteristiques: ${widget.caracteristiques}",
                  textScaleFactor: 1.5),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text("Rôle: ${widget.role}", textScaleFactor: 1.5)
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately since the update, this use is deprecated and no longer works